# Does memoize do a deep copy of perl objects?

Tags: perl, memoization

I designed a function that return a table of objects.  The content of those object is not defined yet, but I would like to make a deep copy between each calls (as in Java).

How does memoize restitute the return value?  Does it makes a deep copy of it?  Nothing say how answers are copied before being returned in the  `Memoize` module help.

```
# How i solved the problem at first....
use Storable qw(dclone); 
my $saved_value ; # undef
sub get_all {
    return dclone($saved_value) if (defined $saved_value) ;
    ....
    $saved_value = dclone( $ans ) ;
    return $ans
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it and see?

```
use Memoize;
sub foo { {bar=>[1..4]} }
memoize('foo');
foo()->{'bar'}[3] = 5;
print foo()->{'bar'}[3];
```

prints 5, so it doesn't make a deep copy.  I leave seeing if it makes even a shallow copy as an excercise.

Comment: Simply returning from a sub makes a shallow copy unless it's an `:lvalue` sub.

Comment: I have the same result.  The function `foo` is reexecuted each time it is called without deferencing it : `foo() ; #reexecution; foo()->{...} ; # no reexecution`